I can't set the row height of a word table to the minimum value in c#
In order for the contents of the table to be displayed, I manually set row 3 of the table in c.docx by selecting "Minimum" in the "Row Height Value" dropdown and it worked. But I can't do it with the following code
The github path for c.docx is  https://github.com/angmangm/test
enter image description here
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<int, float> rowHeights = new Dictionary<int, float>();

    string filePath =  @"D:\c.docx";

    Application wordApp = new Application();
    Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(filePath, ReadOnly: false, Visible: true);

    try
    {
        if (doc.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            // Iterate through each table
            for (int tableIndex = 1; tableIndex <= doc.Tables.Count; tableIndex++)
            {
                Table table = doc.Tables[tableIndex];
                int rowCount = table.Rows.Count;

                Range range = table.Range;

                for (int i = 1; i <= range.Cells.Count; i++)
                {
                    Cell cell = range.Cells[i];

                    string s = cell.Range.Text;

                    float cellBottom = (float)cell.Range.Information[WdInformation.wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage] + cell.Height;

                    // Check each InlineShape inside the cell
                    foreach (InlineShape inlineShape in cell.Range.InlineShapes)
                    {
                        float shapeBottom = (float)inlineShape.Range.Information[WdInformation.wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage] + inlineShape.Height;
                        if (shapeBottom > cellBottom)
                        {

                            if (!rowHeights.ContainsKey(cell.RowIndex))
                            {
                                rowHeights.Add(cell.RowIndex, shapeBottom - cellBottom);
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }

                }

                object what = WdGoToItem.wdGoToTable;
                object which = WdGoToDirection.wdGoToFirst;
                object count = tableIndex;
                wordApp.Selection.GoTo(ref what, ref which, ref count);

                // Iterate through each row
                for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex <= rowCount; rowIndex++)
                {
                    // Selected row, but no need to move at the first row
                    if (rowIndex > 1)
                    {
                        // Move down to the next row
                        wordApp.Selection.MoveDown(WdUnits.wdLine, 1);
                    }

                    // Select the current row
                    wordApp.Selection.Rows.Select();

                    if (rowHeights.ContainsKey(rowIndex))
                    {
                        // Set row height to minimum
                        wordApp.Selection.Rows.HeightRule = WdRowHeightRule.wdRowHeightAtLeast;
                        wordApp.Selection.Rows.Height = wordApp.CentimetersToPoints(float.Parse("0.8"));
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
    }
    finally
    {
        doc.Close(SaveChanges: true);
        wordApp.Quit();
    }
}

Using c# to directly change the height value doesn't work, however, manually dragging the conditional row height works. I don't know what the reason is, or if there is any other way to show the hidden content in the table.
